# Spring Data Repository + JPA + Date + Oracle

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a field lastUpdated of type java.util.Date in an Entity class. I defined methods findByLastUpdated(Date date, Pageable pageable) and findByLastUpdatedGreaterThan(Date date, Pageable pageable) in the repository interface, but they do not work correctly. Examining the logs I noticed that string comparison is used:

```
where table0_.LAST_UPDATED>'2012-03-26 03:03:08.0'
```

The database used is Oracle, so I think a better way of doing the comparison is using the to_date function. I can perhaps do it using native query option, but that doesn't support paging. Any suggestion on how to get methods findByLastUpdated and findByLastUpdatedGreaterThan work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

write the query your self with the 
@Query annotation

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Session 2.2.4